# Spotify clone isn't pushing the albums from spotify account into the playlist array ive created using the react context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify, react-context

I'm new to working with APIs and currently building my first project using React. My goal is to use the React Context API to fetch and display the user's Spotify playlists within my application. I've set up an initial state in the reducer component to store the playlists data. However, when I authenticate my Spotify account and log into my application, I encountered an issue.

upon initial login, I could only see one playlist in my sidebar. However, when I deleted that playlist from my actual Spotify account, no other playlists were rendered in my application. This leaves me stuck and unsure of what the issue could be. I'd appreciate any guidance on how to address these issues and ensure that my application displays all the user's playlists as expected.

In the sidebard component, i,m trying to map over each playlist in the array but nothing is showing.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './Login'
import { getTokenFromUrl } from './spotify';
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js"
import Player from './Player';
import { useDataLayerValue } from './DataLayer';

// Create a new instance of the SpotifyWebApi
const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();

function App() {
  const [{ user, token }, dispatch] = useDataLayerValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    const hash = getTokenFromUrl();
    window.location.hash = "";
    const _token = hash.access_token;

    if (_token) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_TOKEN',
        token: _token,
      });

      spotify.setAccessToken(_token);

      spotify.getMe().then((user) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: user,
        });
      });

      spotify.getUserPlaylists().then((playlists) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_PLAYLISTS",
          playlists: playlists,
        });
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      {token ? (<Player spotify={spotify} />) : (<Login />)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

// Initial state and reducer are separate from the 'App' component
export const initialState = {
    user: null,
    playlists: [],
    playing: false,
    item: null,
    token: null,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_USER':
            return {
                ...state, user: action.user
            }
        
        case 'SET_TOKEN':
            return {
                ...state, token: action.token
            }

        case 'SET_PLAYLISTS':
            return {
                ...state, playlists: action.playlists
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default reducer;

import React from 'react'
import './Sidebar.css'
import SidebarOption from './SidebarOption';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import LibraryMusicIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LibraryMusic';
import { useDataLayerValue } from './DataLayer';

function Sidebar() {
  const [{ playlists }, dispatch] = useDataLayerValue();
  
  return (
    <div className='sidebar'>
      <img className='sidebar_logo' src="https://getheavy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/spotify2019-830x350.jpg" />

      <SidebarOption Icon={HomeIcon} title= "Home" />
      <SidebarOption Icon={SearchIcon} title= "Search" />
      <SidebarOption Icon={LibraryMusicIcon} title= "Your Library" />

      <br/>
      <strong className='sidebar_title'>PLAYLISTS</strong>
      <hr />
      
      {playlists?.items?.map((playlist) => (
        <SidebarOption title={playlist.name} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

As i'm quite new to to using APIs and react, i'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. when i check the dev tools im not given any error messages.